# JavaScript - how to change menu name on click in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am using Gtranslate plugin on WP site and it translates automatically in real time everything on website. Plugin works perfectly, but client wants to change 2 menu item names. As he says plugin translates those words wrong. For example website default language is russian and when you select english language, menu items become - Home and Contact which are generated automatically and he wants those names to be Main and Contact us.

I was thinking to use javacript to instantly change Home and Contact into different words but then header freezes and as I understand my code stops all header functions.

My code:

```
document.getElementById("englishLanguageSwtich").addEventListener("click", function() {
     document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/Home/g, 'Main')
});
```

What script should I use to instantly change menu words into another when different language is selected?

*Edit - script should find those words automatically everytime when page is reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try This-

```
jQuery('#englishLanguageSwtich').on('click', function(event) {

            if ($.trim($(this).val()) === 'Xyz') {
                $(this).val('Abc');
            } else {
                $(this).val('Xyz');
            }
        });
```